# transfer data between 2 databases

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have a requirement to transfer data between databases, namely visual foxpro and mysql.  Every so often, I recieve a foxpro database that has a subset of some data that I have to report on.  Every time I recieve that new database, it will generally have both new data and updates to existing data.  I would like to keep all of the current data in a mysql database.  I have started out by replicating the schema that exists in my foxpro data over to mysql.  When the new foxpro data comes in, I have to look at each record and determine if it exists or not.  if it already exists, I have to update it with the new data.  If it does not exist, I have to add the new data.

I had planned on using nhibernate to handle all of the data access.  My question is wether that is a good way to approach my problem, or if I should use something else, like an etl tool to transfer the data.

If the nhibernate option is viable, do I create duplicate entities for each database and then compare them on an object by object basis?

I hope that makes sense.  Thanks for any thoughts.

Comment: the subset databases will only contain about 50 records at a time.  since it is such a small subset of data, will it be enough to warrant using an etl tool?  or should i just continue with my nhibernate solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NHiberante is not made for transferring large datasets. When you would use NHiberante for this scenario, you would be writing an etl tool around NHiberante, so it is easier to use an Etl tool for this scenario.

Comment: Could you recommend an etl tool that would fit this application?